# Could not create target cluster during upgrade 9.5 to 9.6

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am on ubuntu 16.04, and install postgres 9.5 on it

Then I to upgrade postgres 9.5 to 9.6, and I following [postgresql offical download page](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) to install 9.6:

[image]

then I run `apt install postgresql-9.6`, after install, I run following commands to upgrade

```
# stop the 9.6 
$ sudo pg_dropcluster 9.6 main --stop

# upgrade 9.5 to latest version
$ sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main

sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main
Stopping old cluster...
Notice: extra pg_ctl/postgres options given, bypassing systemctl for stop operation
Disabling connections to the old cluster during upgrade...
Restarting old cluster with restricted connections...
Redirecting start request to systemctl
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: Could not create target cluster
```

Then I trying to using `psql` command to connection old cluster. but errors:

```
$ psql -U postgres -h localhost
psql: FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL on
FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for host "::1", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

seems the pg_hba.conf is wrong, Then I check pg_hba.conf at `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf`, but it seems fine:

```
local   all             postgres                                peer
```

Comment: as stated by pg_upgradecluster: perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en_US:en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to a fallback locale ("en_US.UTF-8").
Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid.
Error: Could not create target cluster

Comment: And the solution is?

Answer (score 19):

The only solution I could find to fix this is to run the following command:

```
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Before proceeding with `sudo pg_upgradecluster 9.5 main`

Comment: Didn't work.. Still Error: The locale requested by the environment is invalid:
  LANG: en_US.UTF-8
  LC_COLLATE: it_IT.UTF-8
  LC_CTYPE: en_US.UTF-8
  LC_MESSAGES: it_IT.UTF-8
  LC_MONETARY: it_IT.UTF-8
  LC_NUMERIC: it_IT.UTF-8
  LC_TIME: it_IT.UTF-8
Error: Could not create target cluster

Answer (score 0):

The solution is a simple as running in your terminal the following commands:

```
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US:en"
$ sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8"
```

Comment: This was part of the solution for me. First I ran Luke's command (export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8 export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8) and then sudo locale-gen "en_US.UTF-8" which turned out working. thanks